# I coded an HTML form that a user fills out, but how do I show that they already sumbitted it if they access that page again?

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, sqlite

In a file called today.html, I have written an extensive form for a user to fill out. I have an application.py file with GET and POST requests such that the user will get the today.html form to fill out in a certain route (GET) and upon submission (POST), that information will be submitted into a SQLite database. I need help with the situation in which the user accesses the GET route again where the form is. I would like them to not be able to fill out the form again but instead be brought to see a message that they already filled it out and see (and potentially edit) what they have already done. How do I do this?

Comment: well since you dont have any code pinned, ill try to answer in the same manner. Just do a GET request to see if the form is already submitted, and then render a message with js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by including extra data in the GET response. I'm assuming the user has a unique ID that helps you make sure they only fill out one form. Then, in the GET request, when they try and fetch the form, just query your database to see if they already submitted a form. If they did, you could include an object like this

```
{
  isFilledOut: true,
  submittedForm: // List of required fields
  submittedFormData: // Object containing data from their previous submission
}
```

for a form that has already been filled out. When `isFilledOut` is true, show the form on the client side with the data they already submitted filled in, allow them to make changes and resubmit if they'd like. If they haven't filled out the form before, your server could return

```
{
  isFilledOut: false,
  submittedForm: // List of required fields
  submittedFormData: null
}
```

In this case, you'd prompt them to fill out the form.

This is a simple example - if you wanted, you could get rid of the boolean and just check if the submitted form is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

On server side, you can chcek last database entry timestamp before answering the GET request.

Also you can set client side cookie to speed up the interface. If the client and server do not match after the GET request, you can always throw an 'out of sinc' error